# Python taking a certain string from a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of informations like this in a list:

```
example = [
    ['68', ' ?', ' 38317', ' 1st-4th', ' 2', ' Divorced', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Female', ' 0', ' 0', ' 20', ' United-States', ' <=50K'],
    ['32', ' ?', ' 293936', ' 7th-8th', ' 4', ' Married-spouse-absent', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', ' 0', ' 0', ' 40', ' ?', ' <=50K']
]
```

aka `example[0]` would be:

```
['68', ' ?', ' 38317', ' 1st-4th', ' 2', ' Divorced', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Female', ' 0', ' 0', ' 20', ' United-States', ' <=50K']
```

and `example[1]` would be:

```
['32', ' ?', ' 293936', ' 7th-8th', ' 4', ' Married-spouse-absent', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', ' 0', ' 0', ' 40', ' ?', ' <=50K']
```

I want to only take the last bit of it, `' <=50K'`, how do I do that?

Comment: You meant `list[0]` and `list[1]`.

Comment: And don't name a list object `list`; that masks the built-in type.

Comment: Yeah it's not called list in the program, it's just a example. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last element of all nested lists with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[sublist[-1] for sublist in example]
```

This would produce `[' <=50k', ' <=50k']`.

Demo:

```
>>> example = [
...     ['68', ' ?', ' 38317', ' 1st-4th', ' 2', ' Divorced', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Female', ' 0', ' 0', ' 20', ' United-States', ' <=50K'],
...     ['32', ' ?', ' 293936', ' 7th-8th', ' 4', ' Married-spouse-absent', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', ' 0', ' 0', ' 40', ' ?', ' <=50K'],
... ]
>>> [sublist[-1] for sublist in example]
[' <=50K', ' <=50K']
```

You could also just address each nested list directly and extract the last element:

```
>>> example[0][-1]
' <=50K'
>>> example[1][-1]
' <=50K'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @KBOB: the expression takes the last element (`[-1]`) from each nested list contained in the outer list.

Answer (score 1):

By default you can index items from a list from the left side of the list to right. Indexing means to get items from a list based on their numeric position in the list. For example:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
myList[0] # This would give me the 1st item of the list; the number 1
myList[1] # would give me the number 2 and so on....
```

If you want to select items from end of your list there are a number of ways to do this, but the easiest way would look something like this:

```
myList[-1] # this would get me the last item of the list; 6 
myList[-2] # would get the second to last item
myList[-3] # would get the third to last item
myList[-4] # would get the fourth to last item
```

Think about this like reverse indexing. So instead of getting items from left to right, you get items from the right to left.

Use positive numbers when you want to get items starting from the left of the list and negative numbers when you want to get items starting from the right.

So your code:

```
['68', ' ?', ' 38317', ' 1st-4th', ' 2', ' Divorced', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Female', ' 0', ' 0', ' 20', ' United-States', ' <=50K']
['32', ' ?', ' 293936', ' 7th-8th', ' 4', ' Married-spouse-absent', ' ?', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', ' 0', ' 0', ' 40', ' ?', ' <=50K']
```

Would look something like this:

```
lastItem = list_of_information[0][-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop if you're looking for a not-particularly-fast way of coding it:

```
new_list = []
for smaller_list in big_list:
     new_list.append(smaller_list[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
last = map(itemgetter(-1), example)
print(last)
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the last element of a list within a list, you would do

```
list[0][len(list[0]) -1]
```

Comment: You don need to consult the list length, as you can address the last element of any sequence with `[-1]` (negative numbers count from the end).